# How Can i find comma separated value in table row in clause in sql query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Can i find comma separated value in table row in clause in sql query 
[image]

```
$model = array(
  array('id' => '1','category_id' => '1','size_id' => '1,2,3','series_id' => '1','model_no' => 'AI-5441','display_height' => '','Weight' => '','image' => '20382mode1.jpg'),
  array('id' => '2','category_id' => '1','size_id' => '3','series_id' => '1','model_no' => 'AI-5741','display_height' => '','Weight' => '','image' => '19391mode1.jpg'),
  array('id' => '3','category_id' => '1','size_id' => '4','series_id' => '1','model_no' => 'AI-5841','display_height' => '','Weight' => '','image' => '8242mode1.jpg')
);


$sql = "SELECT * from model Where size_id IN ('1')";
```

How to write php sql query to get value of `(matching in size_id' => '1,2,3')` or how to match size In('1') into `(size_id' => '1,2,3' of 'id' => '1')` to get the row value.

Comment: Do NOT store comma separated values in DB... think about normalization

Comment: And on this day, Amarjeet learned why database isn't treated as a text file and why we store records in rows, not as comma-separated values in rows. Right Amarjeet?

Comment: I guess you misunderstood the relational databases functioning. As @B001ᛦ saied, it's not a good idea storing comma separated values in single cells

Comment: Thanks for your reply, But i was needed comma separated value for filtering   the size. And working code got from google like ===>   $sizedata =implode("|",$size);
        $query99  .= " and CONCAT(',',size_id, ',') REGEXP ',($sizedata),'";

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$sql = "SELECT * from model Where FIND_IN_SET(id, size_id) > 0 ";
```

Comment: $sizedata =implode("|",$size);
        $query99  .= " and CONCAT(',',size_id, ',') REGEXP ',($sizedata),'";                for multiple search query from google